# Component Services application not running properly on Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2012, com+

I'm new to this old stuff... I've set up my COM+ application (Classic ASP) on Windows Server 2012, but could only get it to run by unchecking "Enforce access checks for this application" in the application properties. It now runs okay, but any time the application tries to hit the database in any way, I get nothing.  I've checked access to the necessary folders (as far as I know) and the user (local user, in the identity tab) has read/write access.  Any ideas?  And is more information needed?

Comment: What kind of database? Is it ADO or else? What kind of connection string, if any?

Comment: Please provide more information about the connection to the database. Can you create an ODBC connection that tests successfully from the same server?

Comment: Sounds like access permission on the DB. Depending on how you connect to the DB this could be an issue with a hard-coded connection string inside the COM component code, or an incorrect run-as identity in the com component settings. How do you think the DB connection works - is it a hard coded connection string, or is the DB using Windows Authentication ?

Comment: Thank you all - we're using SQL server, and I believe it's the DB using Windows Authentication... sadly I work in .NET 99% of the time and don't understand the old code as well. @VanquishedWombat I think you may be right about the incorrect run-as identity in com component settings... I just changed to my own account and finally got the data to show. However, I still have no idea why our normal Services account won't work because I believe it has the same or even more permissions than what my account has.

Comment: So there was a missing Data Access Component that I had to add. For some reason it wasn't working when I first added it, but now it is. Whether it was disabling the com component, then enabling and starting it again... or this thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-error-10016-from-run-time-broker-cannot/3f21a980-7f1e-48e5-85ea-6aa8843ecf40 ... something made it work.  Thank you for helping me go down the right path with the ODBC connection, and using the correct run-as identity.  If any of you three post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably already know, Windows Server releases are an ever-changing minefield of permission issues (aka user identity issues). What worked under 2008 may no longer under 2012.

The components in a classic ASP solution pretty much all have the potential to be running as different identities in the context of Windows.

Typical examples of unexpected identities are System, Network Service, and IUSR.

Where these options bite are, for example:

- In IIS your web site has an assigned app pool in which it runs. The app pool has a user identity assignment;
- In IIS, your virtual folders map to physical folders under Windows and there is access security there;
- With COM you get a further identity option to set - this is the 'run-as' identity, which is the effective user that executes the COM components for you.
- With a database such as MS SQL Server, you get the concept of user connection security which can be set to use Windows user authentication (trust the windows user) or userid/pwd required. So if you use, for example ADODB, in your code you must supply a connection string that you have to match to the connection settings the DB expects and will allow.

From your description I assume that you have the IIS site up and running, and your issue is confined to DB access from the COM components. You need to establish how the COM components connect to the DB and check that the DB will accept the credentials in use. If you are using Windows Authentication for the DB then you need to confirm for sure the run-as identity that is in use. In my setup we create a dedicated Windows user that we set aside specifically to use for COM so that we can be absolutely sure of the identity, and in our most verbose logging from the COM components we capture the run-as identity just to confirm it is all wired up correctly.

We do the same with dedicated Windows users for the IIS app pool user too. In general you are better off being sure which identity is in use by assigning it yourself rather than taking the default. Additionally, the defaults such as Network Service seem to have a diminishing amount of privs in Windows overall.

**Word of caution** - on the other hand do not give your dedicated users more access than they need, for example making them members of the Administrator group when you are frustrated or feeling your way through permission issues. Sure, assign these on a very temporary basis to confirm that access privs are the issue, but be sure to remove such assignments as soon as you possible can.

EDIT: I had this half written when your comment came in. You say that there was a missing component - I had not considered that potential as you seemed to be saying that the config worked but COM did not. Well done for solving your issue. I will leave this answer in place as some of what I have written could be useful for future folks walking the same or similar path.